# Anything new in .Net 4.5 to process better JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio-2012

Is there anything new about JSON handling in .NET 4.5 and VS2012 that would be better than DataContractJsonSerializer? I have seen something about System.JSON. But is it better?

I know there is JSON.NET too, but i am not sure if i am allowed to add another .dll to my project.

Comment: Better in terms of what? Also, Json.Net is a good alternative.. maybe you should find out if you're "allowed" to add it or not. There is also the JavaScriptSerializer class, but it lives in System.Web.Script.Serialization - are you doing anything in the web arena? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: I thought that JavaScriptSerializer should be depricated and replaced (since NET 3.5) through DataContractJsonSerializer. I would request web services and parse their replies.

Comment: I just have to say: "Not allowed to add another dll?" in the modern world of development working with multiple and preferably open source support libraries (not just .net framework) is the best way to stand on the shoulders of othersand achieve much much more. (Nuget == Awesome)

Comment: Microsoft is using JSON.NET in WebAPI, MVC and so on. It's not part of .NET Framework because it's a separate, open source development made by some individual (James Newton-King). I mean, NO WAY: use it.

Comment: @Gero It was deprecated in 3.5, but then reverted in 3.5 SP1. Both classes have their plus and minus points. http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/05/28/javascriptserializer-undeprecated-in-net-35-sp1/

Comment: As others say: Use JSON.NET.

Comment: ServiceStack has a well-rated JSON serializer too

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I believe "Microsoft is using JSON.NET in WebAPI, MVC and so on." is not completely accurate.  From the release notes it sounds like it is being used for WebAPI, but **not for MVC**.

Comment: @AaronLS Comments from a year ago can't be edited anymore :\

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check this link:

[Feature Comparison - Json.NET, DataContractJsonSerializer & JavaScriptSerializer](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)

It has a good feature comparision between **Json.NET, DataContractJsonSerializer & JavaScriptSerializer**. Just have a look at it & then decide which one to use based on your requirement.

Also, check this:

**[ASP.NET MVC 4 & Json.NET :](http://forums.asp.net/p/1810654/5010838.aspx/1?ASP%20NET%20MVC%204%20Release%20Candidate%20released)**

> We (.Net Team) now use and support the popular Json.NET serializer for
>   handling of JSON data. Json.NET is the default JSON      serializer
>   used by ASP.NET Web API and it includes support for data contracts,
>   anonymous types, dynamic types, Dates, TimeSpans, object reference
>   preservation, indenting, camel casing and many other useful
>   serialization features.

Answer (score 6):

You could always use `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavascriptSerializer` - I don't know why more people don't use it, it's been there a while.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: On the linked page, Microsoft now says that you should use Json.NET instead of JavaScriptSerializer.   respectfully...

Comment: Because it's not as good as Json.Net

Comment: Another update on that page: "For .NET Framework 4.7.2 and later versions, use the APIs in the System.Text.Json namespace for serialization and deserialization. For earlier versions of .NET Framework, use Newtonsoft.Json. This type was intended to provide serialization and deserialization functionality for AJAX-enabled applications."

Comment: He said for 4.5, but jsdeserialize is for 4.7.2+